# Why am I getting this valueerror for one set of ride data even though it works perfectly for a different ride

Tags: python, pandas

Hi there I am getting this:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
```

when running these lines:

```
df_nemo_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/finding_nemo_subs.csv", usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'], 
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime']
)
df_nemo_all['ride'] = 'space'
df_nemo_all['open'] = ~((df_space_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_nemo = df_nemo_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_nemo = df_nemo.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_nemo = df_nemo.resample('15Min').ffill()
```

when it works for a different ride such as:

```
df_space_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/space_mountain_dlr.csv", usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'], 
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime']
)
df_space_all['ride'] = 'space'
df_space_all['open'] = ~((df_space_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_space = df_space_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_space = df_space.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_space = df_space.resample('15Min').ffill()
```

Answer (score 2):

You do have duplicates in your index

1. 2017-01-13 09:31:05 has two rows
2. I've excluded this and then it works

```
df_space_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/space_mountain_dlr.csv", usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'], 
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime']
)
df_space_all['ride'] = 'space'
df_space_all['open'] = ~((df_space_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_space = df_space_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_space = df_space.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_space = df_space.resample('15Min').ffill()

df_nemo_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/finding_nemo_subs.csv", usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'], 
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime']
)
df_nemo_all['ride'] = 'space'
df_nemo_all['open'] = ~((df_space_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_nemo = df_nemo_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_nemo = df_nemo.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
c = df_nemo.groupby(level=0).transform("count")
c[c["date"]>1].index.tolist()
df_nemo = df_nemo[~df_nemo.index.isin(c[c["date"]>1].index.tolist())].resample('15Min').ffill()
df_nemo
```

**output**

```
    date    SPOSTMIN    ride    open
datetime                
2017-01-01 09:00:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-01 09:15:00 2017-01-01  5.0 space   True
2017-01-01 09:30:00 2017-01-01  5.0 space   True
2017-01-01 09:45:00 2017-01-01  5.0 space   True
2017-01-01 10:00:00 2017-01-01  5.0 space   True
... ... ... ... ...
2017-01-31 18:45:00 2017-01-31  20.0    space   True
2017-01-31 19:00:00 2017-01-31  20.0    space   True
2017-01-31 19:15:00 2017-01-31  20.0    space   True
2017-01-31 19:30:00 2017-01-31  10.0    space   True
2017-01-31 19:45:00 2017-01-31  10.0    space   True
```

Comment: It helps but now I am getting this error:
```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```
as it is related to the all_data = pd.concat([df_pirates, df_star_tours, df_space, df_nemo]).reset_index()
all_data = (
    all_data
        # Drop any "NaN" values in the column 'ride'
        .dropna(subset=['ride', ])
        # Make datetime and ride a "Multi-Index"
        .set_index(['datetime', 'ride'])
        # Choose the column 'SPOSTMIN'
        ['SPOSTMIN']
        # Take the last index ('ride') and rotate to become column names
        .unstack()
)

Comment: Each data frame has overlapping indexes,  so it's similar issue right.  To make unique add to index.  For example `df_space["dataset"] = "space"
df_nemo["dataset"] = "nemo"
all_data = pd.concat([df_space, df_nemo]).reset_index() 
all_data = ( all_data 
            .dropna(subset=['ride', ]) 
            .set_index(['datetime', 'ride', "dataset"]) 
            .unstack() )
`

Comment: Did that for the other rides but now it gives me this: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'

Comment: also maybe you don't want to `concat` but rather `join` or `merge` so you maintain your set of rows by datetime index and increase number of columns

Comment: Since I am trying to get convert the csv's I got for nearly every ride into an xlsx for each month with each day as a separate sheet so I can analyze the wait times to see if there is a correlation to the time of year and weather with the waits.

Comment: OK - do more analysis,  really know shape and indexing of data.   I think it's all data design and data content rather than technical